# How to write chemical formulas in the title field of .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, biber, chemistry

Some publications have a chemical formula in the title string. 
Journals use very different workarounds to export `.bib` files for these articles on their website. Some are able to create complicate problems when compiling.

What is the best way to denote a chemical formula in the title field of an article in a .bib file?

**Example:**
`Multiferroic phases of Eu1−xYxMnO3` in 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.75.035118

PS: I prefer biber, if it makes a difference which tool I use.

Comment: Packages `mhchem` and `chemformula` come to mind.

Comment: @clemens I use `mhchem` a lot, but was not aware that one can use it for `.bib` and could not find the substring "bib" in the whole `texdoc mhchem` nor in the `texdoc chemformula` manual. Can you give an example, how to use it?

Comment: I'd simply use it as always: `title = {... \ce{H2O}...}`

Comment: @Johannes_B I converted all titles to `title = {... \ce{H2O}...}` as suggested by clemens but could not collect experience where the limits are. I like that it is very simple to handle with scripts afterwards and wrote a python script to rename all pdf files to `bibkey_title.pdf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collecting my comments into an answer: I'd use either package [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) or package [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula). It is then easily possible to use `\ce` (`mhchem`) or `\ch` (`chemformula`) in the bib file:

```
title = {... \ch{H2O}...}
```

Comment: Feedback: I use this method now since 3 years without negative side effects in different setups with `mhchem`,`biber`, `lualatex`, `pdflatex` and `jabref-3.8.2`.